# How to make offset axes in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to create two x-axes, one below the other.

I believe I want to base it off [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/plot_directive/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/figures/simple_axisartist1.py) (which looks like [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/figures/simple_axisartist1.hires.png)), but in particular how do I draw this outside (below) the original axes region, and set major_ticks and major_ticklabels?

Comment: Do you want them to be independent of each other, or linked? (i.e. are you wanting to show, say, one x-axis for meters and one for feet, but plot the same data, or are you wanting to plot two different datasets with the same y-axis, but independent x-axes?)

Comment: @Joe, thanks -- I would like to know both ways, actually. In R for instance, you can just "draw" an axis and it doesn't necessarily have to be linked to anything. Is that possible in matplotlib?

Comment: It is, but generally (even in R) you choose whether you want things to zoom in when you zoom in on the other axis, etc. Usually you want it linked in some way, and there are multiple ways to link things, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example,
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html
shows how to move the spines outwards. The rest depends on what sort of relation do you want of your x-spines (do you want them linked or do you want them independent of each other).

Comment: This opens up a whole new world for me. Thank you!